# Generic option bytes on STM32F4

Tags: stm32f4, stm32f0

I'm currently tuning some code written for an STM32F070, where we use one byte on user option byte to keep some flags between Resets, using:

```
FLASH_ProgramOptionByteData(ADRESSE_OPTION_BYTE_DATA0, status_to_store);
```

Reading carefully the datasheet from our new STM32F446 lets me think that it is no longer possible to use option bytes to store one user byte...

1 - Am I Right with this assertion ? If not, what did I miss ?

2 - Is there some workaround, not involving to rewrite a sector of the flash ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert on stm32, rather still a beginner, but maybe you could have a look on the RTC backup register to hold your data ?